# Social Sharing on various network by single click

Tags: ios, social-networking, sharing, socialshare

I want to share text or images on various social networks (e.g. Google+, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, YouTube) with a single click.

I want to first login to all social networks. Then the user can post text and images on selected option. For reference I want to do like [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/feedtheyumyum/id596669279?l=da&ls=1&mt=8).

Please give me any suggestion or demo for perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

What I would first suggest is to take a look at the various social network's APIs in order to see what's possible on each one and how to implement the various sign-in protocols. Next you should present in some sort of nice way to the user a login prompt for each network, which allows the freedom to choose which networks they want associated with your app. Then I would suggest you research how each you can post to each network. Some require a prompt from the user, and some you can post directly to without the user's consent. Identify which are which and when you allow the user to post something, allow them to select which ones the want to post to, and then present the prompt networks last.